# Comma Separated Job names are not pulling Job ID in for execution in While Loop but working fine when queried a single Job Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-job

Below SQL Script is not able to fetch the Job ID due to some problem while running with comma separated values

Same is running fine if I query JOB ID one by one instead of comma separated

```
dROP TABLE #J_Names
    
    dECLARE @Job_Names nvarchar(max) = 'RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_Address,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_BusinessDescription,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_Char,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_Char_ANZSICr,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_Char_FirmCharacteristic,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_Char_NACE,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_Char_NAICS,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_Char_PrimaryFirmType,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_Char_SICFirmCharacteristic,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CharOwnership,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CharToDate,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CompanyBasic,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CompanyCount,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CompanyExtended,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CompanyLongBusinessDescription,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CompanyOwnership,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CompanyWebsite,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CompareChanges_AlternateCompanyNameAndNativeLanguage,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_CurrentNativeCompanyName,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_FinancialMetric,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_FundInfo,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_TransactionDataDate,
    RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_TransactionDataInteger'
    
    
    DECLARE @sql_xml XML =  CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Job_Names,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)
    SELECT N.value('.', 'sysname') AS j_Name, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by N.value('.', 'sysname') ) ID
    INTO #J_Names
    FROM @sql_xml.nodes('X') AS T(N)
    
    
    Declare @countOfSteps int ;
    Declare @Job_Name sysname ;
    
    
    Select @countOfSteps = Count(*) From #J_Names
    
    While (@countOfSteps) > 0
    BEGIN
    
    
    Select top 1 @Job_Name = (select RTRIM(LTRIM(j_Name)))  From #J_Names order by ID 
    
    --SELECT  CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, job_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = 'RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_BusinessDescription')
    --SELECT CONVERT(sysname, (select RTRIM(LTRIM( @Job_Name))))
    --Select top 1 j_Name From #J_Names order by ID
    --Select top 1 (select RTRIM(LTRIM(j_Name)))  From #J_Names order by ID
    DECLARE @jobId binary(16);

SELECT @jobId = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, job_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name =(select RTRIM(LTRIM(@Job_Name))) )
    
    --print @Job_Name 
    --print 'Hello' 
    --print @jobId
    --SELECT top 1 * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name = N''+@Job_Name+''
    
    IF (@jobId IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @jobId
    END
    
    Delete from #J_Names where j_Name = @Job_Name
    Select @countOfSteps = Count(*) From #J_Names
    
    END
```

For the above script if I run below query manually its giving me the JOB ID, Can anyone help to check if comma separated string is not the correct way to iterate through the loop to get JOBIds

```
SELECT  CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, job_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = 'RDP_Company_CompanyMaintenance_CompareChanges_BusinessDescription')
```

Comment: You'd be better off with a table type parameter.

Comment: As well as using a TVP or table variable, `sp_delete_job` accepts `@job_name` anyway, so you can just pass the job names one by one

Comment: Got it Thank you Guys , I will try this way @Charlieface